# Qcow2 backing image and overlay idea

Tags: kvm-virtualization, snapshot, libvirt, qcow2

I have 2 KVM servers running Windows Guests.  I want to create a Qcow2 image with Windows 7 on it, install the base software needed, and then make that a backing image, read-only, with one qcow2 overlay on top which will be read write.  I will take a copy of the backing image and put it on the second server as well, then whenever I need to create a clone, I only need to make a copy of the overlay and create a new VM on the second server with the identical backing image, and this overlay as the writable image.  This should be a fast way to create point in time clones of the first server, and will save me time since the overlay should be smaller than using a single qcow2 image, yes?

libvirt 0.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have to keep in mind that once you create that template image, it has to remain static and cannot be changed, or all the VMs derived from it will lose their base data.

Comment: I think this is the solution I am going to use, I am abandoning the other way where I used KVM and ESXi together, it is a nightmare.

Comment: What you really need to start looking at is using oVirt or RHEV, where templates can be used as well as centralised storage instead of manual moving around of images. You also get to talk to proper technical support who have much more information than anyone on a forum would